# How to implement an auto-scaling solution requiring synchronous subscription?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I have to process requests published in a Pub/ Sub Topic by the users of my "service" in a Python application, having a main loop.

Each instance of the service will only be able to process one request a time due to the limitation of the application. Burst of requests (~10 at the beginning, growing to ~ 10^6/7) will mix into mostly total idle time. The cold start time of the application is very high compared to the processing time for a single request.

My code will be a plug-in, which polls the subscription, calls methods in the application based on it and then saves data in Cloud Storage and Big Query.

I have read through the cloud documentation and it seems that Cloud Run is the right solution, together with the synchronous subscription API in Python. Cloud Functions I excluded, because it seems more be suited for asynchronous stuff.

However, I did not fully understand how the auto-scaling works. Basically it would have to do this based on the average processing time for each request and the length of the queue, considering the average start-up time of a container.

Unfortunately I did not find a tutorial or example for such a use-case, especially not really explaining how the auto-scaling happens in detail.

Does anyone have something like that or could one explain me here?

Comment: Hi @Torsten Knodt, Can you clarify your requirement?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar I am not really sure how to describe it better. The thing is that the "main program", over which I have no control and is written in PyQt, will instantiate a class I provide and call a method in there. Beyond short initialization stuff, my method is "only" allowed to create a QT thread for background stuff and communicates with the main program via signals.